# Forbidden Server at localhost Port 80!! error while opening local host

Tags: php, apache

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.4.9
>   (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

The above statement was given by the browser. I'm new to wamp so please help me out. I've tried other solutions which are available on the forum but still this message pops up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most ISPs (Internet Service Providers) don't allow access to Port 80 or 25. Try another port that isn't used, refer to [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

Comment: indeed I've used most of of the ips still itbmalfunctions